# github.com not reachable when building application from openshift origin 3.11

Tags: git, docker, okd

I'm new to docker and okd. I'm using okd 3.11 all in one in my ssdnodes vm running CentOS Linux 8 (Core). Installed it using oc cluster up --public-hostname="hostname" --base-dir="/path". When I try to build an application from api or cli I get the error at git clone.

````
WARNING: timed out waiting for git server, will wait 1m4s
error: fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/sclorg/cakephp-ex/':  Could not resolve host: github.com; Unknown error```

I tried by turning off firewalld but that did not help.
I can ping github.com from main VM but from docker-registry its not pinging any external url/ip.

cat /etc/resolv.conf
```nameserver 172.30.0.x```

oc adm diagnostics NetworkCheck
```Info:  Skipping network diagnostics check. Reason: Not using openshift network plugin.```
````

Comment: I can ping the IP of github/google from docker registry container but not able to ping github.com or google.com. Any suggestions?